# TCl-Tk How to catch floating point numbers from a file

Tags: file, floating-point, tcl, tk-toolkit

i'm finding some troubles working on a file containing some floating numbers.
These are some rows from my file:

```
174259  1.264944 -.194235 4.1509e-5
174260  1.264287 -.191802 3.9e-2 
174261  1.266468 -.190813 3.9899e-2
174262  1.267116 -.193e-3 4.2452e-2
```

What i'm trying to do is to find the row where is my desire number (e.g "174260") and extract the following three numbers.

this is my code:

```
set Output [open "Output3.txt" w]
set FileInput     [open "Input.txt" r]

set filecontent [read $FileInput]
set inputList [split $filecontent "\n"]

set Desire 174260
set FindElem [lsearch -all -inline $inputList $Desire*]

set Coordinate [ regexp -inline -all {\S+} $FindElem ]

set x1 [lindex $Coordinate 1]
set y1 [lindex $Coordinate 2]
set z1 [lindex $Coordinate 3]

puts  $Output  "$x1 $y1 $z1"
```

Using the regexp method for a string "{\S+}" i obtain as last character a curly brackets:

```
 1.264287 -.191802 3.9e-2}
```

I don't know how to extract only the numbers value and not the entire string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be really tempted in this case to go with the simplest possible option.

```
set Output [open "Output3.txt" w]
set FileInput [open "Input.txt" r]

set Desire 174260

while {[gets $FileInput line] >= 0} {
    lassign [regexp -inline -all {\S+} $line] key x1 y2 z1
    if {$key == $Desire} {
        puts $Output "$x1 $y1 $z1"
    }
}

close $FileInput
close $Output
```

Failing that, your problem is that you're using `lsearch -all -inline`, which returns a list, and then processing that list as a string with `regexp`. You should handle that using:

```
foreach found $FindElem {
    set Coordinate [ regexp -inline -all {\S+} $found ]

    set x1 [lindex $Coordinate 1]
    set y1 [lindex $Coordinate 2]
    set z1 [lindex $Coordinate 3]

    puts  $Output  "$x1 $y1 $z1"
}
```

This isn't really as good as just understanding the lines properly in the first place, and working with the data one line at a time is pretty trivial.